# Potting compound in a light fitting? Does it need restoring?

Tags: electrical, led, safety

I acquired some used workshop LED light fixtures from the local recyclers.  They've taken to cutting line cables off to avoid having to get electricians to test electrical items before sale, for liability reasons.  Also means the sticker price is lower than for a guaranteed working item.

I expected that the line cable was crimped or similar and a replacement would be straight-forward, so I could test if the light works.   I figured $5 was a good gamble, so why not?

[image]

On disassembly I find the inside of the driver area is completely filled with grey rubbery compound so that it almost completely covered the components and the incoming power wires.  It cuts easily with a sharp knife, but I used a blunt one to "tear" the compound away not knowing where the components were buried.

[image]
  <sub>This is my second effort, and I did much better.  The first one has about 3x as much compound removed and I can see many more components along with some copper wire.</sub>

I dug around with a blunt tool and got a new input lead connected.  Light tests out fine, but now I have a crater in the potting.  When reassembled, it IS possible to fit an adult sized finger through the gap and into the exposed area.

The reasons for not adding something:

- Light will be suspended high up out of reach
- Possible disagreement between existing and new compound - potentially incompatible

[image]

And yes it works exceedingly well.  Sticker on the back says **26,000 Lumens**

```
 HUGO Lighting
 Model HB200-5
 Wattage 200W 2.7A max
 Voltage 100-240VAC 50/60 Hz
 Lumen Output:: 26,000lm 5000k
```

[image]

**TLDR** Should I add some compound to the excavation?  If so, what should I use?   Would RTV Silicon be acceptable?

Comment: Check the unit for recalls. I bet it was recalled due to a safety issue and that's why they lopped the cord.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica possible, but the "ecoshed" cuts off most cords. Maybe  1 item in 20 there still has a cord.   I doubt the staff would go and look for recall info on what is essentially rubbish.

Comment: I did a quick google and found the importer's website at https://www.hugolighting.co.nz/product/hb200-5/ and there's no mention of a recall of anything, so while one can't prove a negative, odds are good its not a recall given its still a current product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry about replacing the potting compound once the cover is replaced it will be fine.

Some mfg’s use the compound to prevent vibration failures, some of the compounds are thermal in nature and some are to prevent tampering.

You have not exposed the components so I would not worry about it.